# How to write maths

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

In the sentence below, which expression is better to choose: "their multiplications" or "their multiplication" :

*"This identification allows us, first, to present a new polar form of quaternions, then to represent the unit quaternions on the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and to interpret **their multiplications** geometrically"*

I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I think the singular sounds better.

Comment: Also, if you mean to interpret just the multiplication of the *unit* quaternions geometrically, I would say “and interpret” instead of “and to interpret.” (The latter makes it parallel to “to represent” and suggests it refers to all the quaternions.)

Comment: I suggest "products" instead of "multiplications".